# How to use structure arrays in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I´m writing this question because I´m not sure with the use of "structure arrays". I did a matrix from keyboard with different inputs (integer, float, etc.) using the "dtype" command. Then, I want find repeated elements in the column "p" and "q", when I have these elements, I want to sum the respective elements from column "z". Thanks. This is my Python code:

```
from numpy import *
from math import *
from cmath import *
from numpy.linalg import *
number_lines_=raw_input("Lines:")
numero_lines=int(number_lines_)
ceros=zeros((numero_lines,1))
dtype=([('p',int),('q',int),('r',float),('x',float),('b',complex),('z',complex),('y',complex)])
#print dtype
leng=len(dtype)
#print leng
yinfo=array(ceros,dtype)
#print shape(yinfo)
if numero_lines>0:
    for i in range(numero_lines):
        p_=raw_input("P: ")
        p=int(p_)
        if p>0:
            yinfo['p'][i]=p
            #print yinfo
            q_=raw_input("Q: ")
            q=int(q_)
            if q>0 and q!=p:
                yinfo['q'][i]=q
                r_=raw_input("R: ")
                r=float(r_)
                yinfo['r'][i]=r
                x_=raw_input("X: ")
                x=float(x_)
                yinfo['x'][i]=x
                b_=raw_input("b:")
                b=complex(b_)
                yinfo['b'][i]=complex(0,b)
                yinfo['z'][i]=complex(yinfo['r'][i],yinfo['x'][i])
                yinfo['y'][i]=1./(yinfo['z'][i])
 # print "\n"
 print yinfo
 print type(yinfo)
 print yinfo.shape
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest some changes:

```
import numpy as np  # not *
....
numero_lines=int(number_lines_)
...
# don't use numpy function names as variable names
# even the np import
dt=np.dtype([('p',int),('q',int),('r',float),('x',float),('b',complex),('z',complex),('y',complex)])
...
yinfo=np.zeros((numero_lines,),dtype=dt)
# make a zero filled array directly
# also make it 1d, I don't think 2nd dimension helps you
# if numero_lines>0:   omit this test; range(0) is empty

# link each of the fields to a variable name
# changing a value of yinfo_p will change a value in yinfo
yinfo_p=yinfo['p']
yinfo_q=yinfo['q']
# etc

for i in range(numero_lines):
    p_=raw_input("P: ")
    p=int(p_)
    if p>0:
        yinfo_p[i]=p
        #print yinfo
        q_=raw_input("Q: ")
        q=int(q_)
        if q>0 and q!=p:
            yinfo_q[i]=q
            r_=raw_input("R: ")
            r=float(r_)
            yinfo_r[i]=r
            x_=raw_input("X: ")
            x=float(x_)
            yinfo_x[i]=x
            b_=raw_input("b:")
            b=complex(b_)
            yinfo_b[i]=complex(0,b)

 # dont need to fill in these values row by row
 # perform array operations after you are done with the input loop
 yinfo_z[:] = yinfo_r + 1j*yinfo_x
 yinfo_y[:] = 1./yinfo_z
```

Alternatively I could have defined

```
yinfo_p = np.zeros((numero_lines,), dtype=int)
yinfo_q = ...
```

After filling in all the `yinfo_*` values I could assemble them into a structured array - if that's what I need for other uses.

```
yinfo['p'] = yinfo_p
etc.
```

This isn't a very good use of structured arrays; as I tried to show with the `yinfo_b` variables, you are using each field as though it was a separate 1d array.

I haven't actually run these changes, so there might be some errors, but hopefully they will give you ideas that can improve your code.